ZeroMQ Timeout if client cannot connect to the server
I want to have an exclusive pair of 2 sockets to allow bilateral communication between 2 separate applications. I use ZeroMQ cppzmq.
In the client, I am checking if the server is live by a handshake.
It could be the case that the server is not online yet, when I start the client.
This causes the client to hang at the moment, and i need to force quit the application.
I am trying to implement a timeout on the client side, to exit the application after no handshake OK message is received. I thought I could do this with ZMQ_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, ZMQ_SNDTIMEO or ZMQ_RCVTIMEO. Unfortunately, this does not work as I intended, the client keeps hanging at the end of the program.
How can I stop all blocking actions at the return of the program? Please note that this is an MVCE, and I am running this in a bigger application. So simply checking if (incoming_msg != "OK") exit(0); works here, but is not a usefull solution.
Server:
// server.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, zmq::socket_type::pair);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true)
    {
        zmq::message_t incoming;
        auto ret = socket.recv(incoming, zmq::recv_flags::none);
        std::string incoming_str = incoming.to_string();
        std::cout << "Received request: " << incoming_str << std::endl;

        if (incoming_str == "connected")
        {
            std::cout << "  Sending OK" << std::endl;
            zmq::message_t ack(2);
            memcpy(ack.data(), "OK", 2);
            socket.send(ack, zmq::send_flags::none);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

Client:
// client.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

int main()
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, zmq::socket_type::pair);
    int timeout_ms = 100;
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, timeout_ms);
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SNDTIMEO, timeout_ms);
    socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, timeout_ms);
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    // send "connected"
    zmq::message_t msg(9);
    memcpy(msg.data(), "connected", 9);
    socket.send(msg, zmq::send_flags::none);

    // receive "OK"
    zmq::message_t incoming;
    auto ret = socket.recv(incoming, zmq::recv_flags::none);
    std::string incoming_str = incoming.to_string();

    std::cout << "Received from server: " << incoming_str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


In general I'd use a socket monitor socket to get information on the status of the underlying connection, and use that in with calls to zmq_poll() which is where I'd also have a timeout. Please note that the advice in the ZMQ API reference is to not use PAIR sockets over tcp. From the manual: "...their inability to auto-reconnect coupled with the fact new incoming connections will be terminated while any previous connections (including ones in a closing state) exist makes them unsuitable for TCP in most cases".

"How can I stop all blocking actions at the return of the program"

Just before your application terminates destroy the zmq::context object. This will do two things

Unblock all the blocking socket calls (e.g your recv)
block itself until all the zmq sockets are closed



Its then your responsibility to handle the unblocked recv and close the socket.
Check the return value and if its == ETERM close the socket. At that point (if all sockets are closed) the zmq::context will unblock/continue and your application will exit.
